# Roslyn Scripting API throws Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using roslyn ScriptingAPI throws an exception says:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

When compiling multiple string scripts, one by one, like this:

```
foreach (string script in scripts)
{
  var evalFunc = CSharpScript.Create(script, roslynOptions, typeof(ParamsVM));
  evalFunc.Compile();
  cachedScripts.Add(rule.Formula,evalFunc);
}
```

I thought I can save all compiled scripts to use them later on thousands of data items, but the memory reach ~4GB because of this saving.
If I used each script on time of need (later when I iterate over the data items) then each script will be compiled again and again.

What's the solution for such a use case ?

Comment: can you not just cache the most frequently used?

Comment: All the scripts are used on all the data set I have

Comment: @BugFinder : I suspect that unless loaded into a different app-domain, it's impossible to jetison the "in-memory DLLs" that this process creates. When an appdomain loads code, it's a one way process. You can unload appdomains though... At which point, it's probably better to adopt something like MEF to get the job done.

Comment: You can save just the compiled code and let the GC reclaim all the compile-time artifacts by just holding onto the delegate from script.CreateDelegate() instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432940/how-to-use-roslyn-c-sharp-scripting-in-batch-processing-with-several-scripts/43456926#43456926).

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the idea of using `Roslyn Scripting API` for evaluating my scripts.
I went toward using `Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`, I iterated over all the scripts and formed (as string) a complete class (with all its `using` parts and `namespace`) then I compiled it (consider it as caching) so after that I can call the methods dynamically by reflecting the assembly I already compiled and pass to it the arguments it needed.